# How to send more than 1 parameters in url and how to access them in my GET route in Node.js/Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Currently I'm successfully able to send 1 parameter and then access it in my GET router, however, I am not sure how to add more than 1 parameters and how to access them in my GET router. Here's my code showing how I send and get 1 parameter.

EJS file:

```
<a class='stickyContainer homePage' href='/image/<%= results[i].id %>'></a>
```

Router file:

```
router.get('/:id', function(req, res, next) {
    res.send(req.params.id);
});
```

Now when I click any of my images, I am send to a URL like that http://localhost:8087/image/21, however I would like to be send to something like http://localhost:8087/image/Beautiful-Image-21, where Beautiful-Image is the name of the image and 21 is the Id of the image. How am I supposed to chain the parameters like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your route like this

```
router.get('/:name/:id', function(req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.params.id)
    console.log(req.params.name)
    res.send(req.params.id);
});
```

And call it like this

`http://localhost:8087/image/Beautiful-Image/21`

Comment: But I want the URL to be http://localhost:8087/image/Beautiful-Image-21. Is this not possible or correct way to do it?

Comment: @Bobimaru I don't think that's possible directly. In that case, you have to split the string `Beautiful-Image-21` to get the id and name separately.